# Access/Display contentid in the view of a model?

Tags: episerver

I have created a new block type in episerver, and I am working on editing it's corresponding view. I would like to be able to display the contentid of the block in my html so that I can work some magic using javascript.

How can I get the contentid of the block from within it's view?

I would like to be able to do this:

```
<div class="something" data-id="@Model.contentid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the block instance to `IContent` and then use `@Model.ContentLink.ID`.

So, something like:

```
<div class="something" data-id="@(((IContent)Model).ContentLink.ID)"></div>
```

Reason for the cast is that the `IContent` interface is only implemented by the proxy class for your block type, which is why you won't find the `ContentLink` property on a `BlockData` instance directly.

If you're interested in the details: https://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Johan-Bjornfot/Dates1/2012/11/Shared-blocks--IContent/

Comment: Thank you, I assume this has to be done in the controller? My block does not have a controller. Is there any inline way to do this directly in the view?

Comment: Your markup appears to be in a Razor view (.cshtml file), so you could do it there. Updated answer with sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I am using Razor.